# Kubernetes-Client Rest Call from Client to Service or Pod

Tags: kubernetes, service, client, cluster-computing, call

I have a Kubernetes cluster which i manage provisioning of configs, storages, services and statefulsets using the kubernetes-client library for .NET. The provisioning is working fine and the necessary resources are up and running.

Normally, I also have provisioned some ingresses, because there is the need to make some web calls in order to create some connectors, for example debezium connectors:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" <domain or ip>:8083/connectors/ --data "@connectors/source.json"
```

Call something like this though the kubernetes client programmatically

```
http://<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<port>/connectors/
```

Is possible to make a call to the service from inside the cluster as I am using already the kubernetes client without using any ingress and public calls?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your use case. Example would help to understand `what` calls `what`.

If you mean that some `pod` calls Kubernetes `service` inside a cluster, yes you can access Kubernetes service using its name if it has `clusterIP` thanks for [Cluster Networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/).

For example (`k=kubectl`)

```
k get svc
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)          AGE
dind            ClusterIP      10.43.150.27    <none>         2375/TCP         89d

k get pod
NAME                              READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
jenkins-0                         2/2     Running     7          7d17h
```

If you want to access service `dind` from `jenkins-0` pod (one of its containers), run shell inside it and access the service by name:

```
k exec -it jenkins-0 bash
jenkins@jenkins-0:/$ curl http://dind:2375/version
{"Platform":{"Name":"Docker Engine - Community"}
...
```

I also wrote an article on [Kubernetes Networking](https://www.rokpoto.com/kubernetes-networking-explained/) which you may find useful.

Comment: The question is to use the kubernetes client from C# to make the call. For example to make a call to http://<namespace>.svc.cluster.local/connectors/

Comment: You can do that and you'll need to use `service` name in this case as well. Also note that by default, `default` service account is used in each pod for k8s api calls. You may need to use service account that has permissions to perform operations (HTTP verbs) your use case entails.

Comment: @rock do you have an example with a kubernetes-client sdk making a call to a pod's service?